# The probability to pick a spade and then a heart.

Tags: probability, card-games

From a standard deck of playing cards, you pick a card and without returning the card you pick a second card.  What is the probability that you picked a spade and then a heart?

Comment: The deck of cards has 52 cards: 14 are spades, 14 are hearts and 28 are the rest. I recommend, thinking about computing your probability in a simpler scenario supposing that you have 8 cards: 2 spades, 2 hearts and 4 the rest. Then try scaling your answer to the 52 cards. Try writing the cases by hand

Comment: @Jack I think you overcount. There are 13 cards of a suit.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 suits and each suit has 13 cards. In your first draw, you will get a spade with probability 1/4 (each suit is equally likely). Now that you have a spade, there are 51 cards (12 spades and 13 each of the other 3 suits). Now your probability of getting a heart is 13/51. So the probability of getting a spade followed by a heart is $1/4 \times 13/51$.